# SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table when try to create new user

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new in laravel php and i try to create a new user with api post request and when i send this request i have a porblem when i do it
I use psgql and laravel 9. i use that
[link](https://techtoolindia.com/how-to-use-laravel-sanctum-for-api-authentication) to do this and custom somthing

This is my code:
i has User model like

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens,HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'user';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


}
```

and here is my AuthController to create new user

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     *  Create User
     * @param Request $request
     * @return User|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function createUser(Request $request){
        try{
            $validateUser = Validator::make($request->all(),[
                'first_name'=>'required',
                'last_name'=>'required',
                'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email',
                'password'=>'required'
            ]);

            if($validateUser->fails()){
                return response()->json([
                    'status'=>false,
                    'message'=>'validation error',
                    'errors'=>$validateUser->errors()
                ],401);
            }
            $user = User::create([
                'first_name'=>$request->first_name,
                'last_name'=>$request->last_name,
                'email'=>$request->email,
                'password'=> Hash::make($request->password)
            ]);
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>true,
                'message'=>'User created successfully',
                'token'=>$user->createToken("API TOKEN")->plainTextToken
            ],200);
        }
        catch (\Throwable $th){
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>false,
                'message'=>$th->getMessage()
            ],500);
        }

    }
}
```

and i got problem when i send post request json
like

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation \"users\" does not exist\nLINE 1: select count(*) as aggregate from \"users\" where \"email\" = $1\n                                          ^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from \"users\" where \"email\" = something@abc.com)"
}
```

please help me

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, it would help if you extracted a [mcve] to focus on the issue and to include here. Problem is, there is way too little info in here. Apart from the bit of code and the error message, everything is missing, like e.g. what you did with that program of yours and its database.

Comment: You appear to have customised the name of the User table. Sanctum expects it to be named users as per convention unless you tell it otherwise in its config. I suggest you save yourself wasted time and headaches and follow the Laravel conventions. Change your User table migration back to be named users.

Comment: In your model you use the table name `user`, and in your controller, in the validation rules, you use the table `users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:❌

```php
 'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email',
```

Use this:✅

```php
'email'=>'required|email|unique:user,email',
```

Note the *table name* defined in your `User` Model is `user`.

Hence, that has to be reflected in your validation rules as well.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to check you table in in validation

`'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email',`
replace **users** to **user**

Comment: The same answer has been provided already.

Comment: but its  shortest

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong table name in the validation, you need to replace 'users' by 'user' :

**'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email'**  to be **'email'=>'required|email|unique:user,email'**

Comment: How is your answer different from the one accepted earlier?

Comment: it could be easy to understand